# How to use Apex:InlineEditSupport for Apex:Detail or Apex:Tab and change color of modified values?

Tags: apex, visualforce, inlineeditsupport

I have a Visualforce Page. Its just replicate tab/detail view to visualforce page. Nothing fancy. Very simple. But I am not able to add InlineEditSupport in this. I want to change the font color when a user tries to edit a record using inline editing. Any suggestions how to do this?

Answer (score 4):

This should be very easy and straight forward. Assuming you apply it to YourObject__c, I usually do it like that:

```
<apex:page standardController="YourObject__c"  extensions="YourCtrExtension" >
    <apex:form id="form">
    <apex:inlineEditSupport event="ondblclick" />
    <apex:detail subject="{!YourObject__c.Id}" showChatter="true" inlineEdit="true" relatedList="false" />
</apex:form>
```

The controller extension can be omitted, if you have no extra functionality.

And to change the color of modified values shouldn't be too hard either. Just add a style tag in front of the form:

```
<style>
.inlineEditModified {
    color: blue;
    font-weight: bold;
}
</style>
```

Now the default orange indicators should render blue.